# JPA, @OneToMany, @ManyToOne no JoinTable, ForiegnKey never set?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have the following two classes in a oneToMany and a ManyToOne

The  Parent Class:

```
@Entity    
class ParentBean{

@GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
private Long id_parent;

@Column( name = "NAME" )    
private String name;

@OneToMany( mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
private List<ChildBean> revisionList;
}
```

the child class:

```
@Entity    
class ChildBean {

@GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
private Long id_child;
private String name;

@ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
@JoinColumn( name = "ID_PARENT", nullable = false )
private ParentBean parent;
}
```

I use the following code to create the beans:

```
ParentBean parent = new ParentBean();
parent.setName( "test parent");

List<ChildBean> revList = new ArrayList<>();

ChildBean child = new ChildBean();
child.setName( "test child" );

revList.add ( child );

parent.setRevisionList( revList );
```

I then use this to write the bean structure to the database...

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

@Override
public void addDrawing( FtDrawing drawingIn )
{

    em.persist( drawingIn );

    em.flush();
}
```

The parent bean is written but I get the following error and the child is never written

> Caused by:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Column 'ID_PARENT' cannot be null

I've looked around on the web and followed several different examples and they all seem to be the same as what i'm doing...  My database is MySQL and I have to two primary keys set to auto_increment.  One last thing.  I didn't specify a foreign key in the child table to relate back to parent table... is this required?  I was using an older version of hibernate and it wasn't necessary...

thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Before persisting a `ChildBean`, its `parent` field must be set. The problem is, when you add the child to the parent's list, the child's parent field is not set. Set it before it's persisted (when cascading persisting the parent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work, you have to set the `parent` field of the `ChildBean`. If you don't, the field is null, and your code says that it cannot be null. So you have to do this :

```
ParentBean parent = new ParentBean();
parent.setName( "test parent");

List<ChildBean> revList = new ArrayList<>();

ChildBean child = new ChildBean();
child.setName( "test child" );

revList.add ( child );

child.setParent( parent ); // don't forget this.
parent.setRevisionList( revList );
```

For convenience, you can write a `addChild` method in the `ParentBean` which will automatically do it, and then you will never have to worry about that :

```
public class ParentBean {
    /* ... */

    public void addChild(ChildBean child) {
        this.revisionList.add(child);
        child.setParent(this);
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

Then, just call it instead of `parent.getRevisionList().add(child)`.

Edit : I think there are couple more problems in your code.

- Your `ParentBean` and `ChildBean` should contain an `@Id` annotation where you put the `@GeneratedValue` one.
- IMO, the foreign key to parent in the child table is required. I don't see any reason not to set it.